# wifi & bluetooth not working on my hp compaq note15 laptop

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek-wireless

Please, 
i'm new to ubuntu 14.04 and i can't connect to wifi available. I'm using hp compaq note 15 (model : 15-s008TURev). But i can use an ethernet cable to connect to the internet. there's actually no option for me to see available WIFI connections.

tks

Comment: Make sure that your laptop wireless switch physically turned ON. Then go to *system-settings* and select *network* there you can find the wireless network options

Comment: please if you could do as @VinuKevy, and add screen shots it help.

Comment: @vinukevy.        It's already turned ON. I think wireless & Bluetooth driver's are missed from my laptop. I don't know how to fix it . please help me

Answer (score 0):

**If so, do install wifi drivers**

Open terminal and type in

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

Then enter your password

[image]

This window opens up eventually, select *Additional Drivers* tab and your driver will show up if you're connected to proper internet through ethernet cable and *do install it*.

That's it.

Comment: tks, 
 
@vinukevy sir but **nothing found**. If u dont mind plz give me ur whatsapp or telegram number